# Sailsjs CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue

Tags: javascript, api, cors, sails.js

I'm currently experiencing CORS origin issues with a response from sails API endpoint. I already set `allowRoutes: true and allowOrigin: "*"` options in security.js file but I still get the `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` what am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 3):

Add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `headers` of config/cors.js